# Possible to search multiple AD forests with the same query?

Tags: ldap, active-directory

I have two domain controllers configured with non-contiguous namespaces. There is a two-way forest trust and crossRef objects set up between domains. I can successfully execute an LDAP search for any particular object in either domain. However, I would like to be able to execute a single LDAP search for all User objects in both directories pointed against a single baseDN.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, setting up OpenLDAP is probably going to be more work than you want to go through for the convenience of running one LDAP query.

I would create a VBScript / PowerShell script to take a supplied query, execute it against both domains, and return the results to you.

This would be a fairly simple script to write. If I get some time later tonight and you haven't found a suitable solution (and you're interested), I'll try to cook one up.

Comment: Thanks for the offer to write the script- I don't think that will work for my client but it's a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any LDAP client tools will automatically perform the same query over two servers (unless the first server returns a referral to the second).

You could set up a LDAP proxy, using [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org) 's `meta` backend, which acts as a proxy to integrate several naming contexts from several different servers in one single tree. I have successfully used it to do just this on several Windows 2003 domains. Add the `rewrite` overlay and you can represent both domains under one LDAP tree.

For example, if you have several AD domains named `COMPANYONE.COM` and `COMPANYTWO.NET`, you would end up with the following LDAP tree:

> - o=all-companies
>
>   - dc=companyone,dc=com,o=all-companies
>
>     - Objects from domain `COMPANYONE`
>   - dc=companytwo,dc=net,o=all-companies
>
>     - Objects from domain `COMPANYTWO`

Thus, you could base searches on the base DN `o=all-companies`, which would return entries from both servers.

Check out [OpenLDAP's back-meta man page](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd-meta&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&format=html).